# What is toIsoString() in moment and why does it gives me time lesser then current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Ok I have a scenario where I am comparing dates with dates in database. The dates are in this format  **"2016-11-16T18:00:19.000Z"** and when I use

```
var time = moment().toISOString();
```

I expect to get current date in the above format but it gives me a result which is around few hours behind. 
So what is toIsoString.??

Comment: It returns the time in ISO format, using UTC. If you are "east" of the prime meridian then it will be an earlier time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn about `toIsoString()` see [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

It is a few hours behind because it is not relative to your timezone.

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

Comment: so if the dates are stored using toIsoString format and if I need to show when were the dates stored I am getting the wrong value from the db.

Comment: or do need to again format them to match current timing. I am just confused here.

Comment: Use `Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z').toLocaleString()` to format to match the local timezone.

Comment: one more question : Why should we do the trouble of storing date in ISOString format to later change it to current time for computation etc.

Comment: @sacDahal it might be because then you can convert it to the local timezone for the person viewing the page

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the difference is the same as the difference between your local time and UTC?

With Moment, the date is always interpreted as **local time** ([1](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/)). The toISOString function always returns a timestamp in **UTC**, even when the parameter is in local time ([2](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)).